# My WordPress Website loads extremely slow

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a WordPress website and it loads extremely slow. It is on AWS and when I connect to instance and command type top everything looks fine except in cloudwatch it spikes to 100% CPU Utilization.

When I click on a link on the website the .php-fpm.bin reaches %CPU that it shows when I run the command 'top' is between 20-22% and 4 or 5 of them are running which it shows as to reach 100% and that's when clicking on only 1 link.

How can I fix this and improve load time of website.

It is currently on t1.micro, I could upgrade instance but it should work fine on this. I know a couple people who are also hosting website on t1.micro instance and it works perfectly fine. I couldn't get them to help me out with it though.

I have checked all plugins and activated and deactivated all one by one and currently only plugins required are active. There are currently no cache plugins or anything like that as I am just sorting out the settings for W3 Total Cache.

I hope someone can help me out with this please
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to the default `WP Twenty Fourteen` theme and see it the loading time is better, if it is - then the problem is with your theme.

Check for meaningless functions or `curl` calls in theme's `functions.php` file (if it is `warez` theme). Also check your theme's `style.css` file and observe if you use URL of backgrounds which come from different domain or if the theme import external style-sheets with `@import` rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I launch website on another t1.micro instance it doesn't reach 100% as much as the live one but this one isn't even in use and still reaches 100%. I launched it about 24 hours ago and the new instance reached 100% total of 3 times, it just peaked and dropped. The live website reaches 100% at least 10 time, sometimes more and stays there for 1min - 10 minutes. Why could that be? I will check the functions.php and style.css now. thanks

Comment: I just checked functions.php and style.css and they both look all ok, what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, T1 micro instances are just to small for website hosts. Their performance is variable, memory low and there is no guaranteed, amount of CPU reserved for you.

This page outlines how and when AWS will purposefully reduce the performance of T1-Micro instances:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html

Simplest fix is to upgrade to a larger instance.

Comment: That is my back up but I need it to work with the micro instance too. Instance doesn't shutdown or crash or anything, it would just peak at 100%, be really slow, go down for a bit and then peak again. Thanks

Comment: Added a link that explains what is likely happening, any why you probably won't be able to 'fix' it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using W3 Total Cache try disabling (if you've turned on) the "Object Cache" feature